# Generate 5000 records in 2 columns of random number that being unique

Tags: excel, random, excel-formula, excel-2013

How I can generate 5000 records in 2 columns of random numbers between 1 and 100 that being unique.

For example:

```
 A            B
----------------
 1            98
 1            23
 37           98
 6            56
 93           18
 .            .
 .            .
 .            .
```

thanks

Comment: if they are all unique they can't be random!

Comment: Do you mean no number in column A should be in column B? or you mean only unique rows?

Comment: **Do you want 5000 rows or 2500 values in each column??**

Comment: Yes. 5000 rows in 2 columns...2500 in each ones

Comment: @khajvah: I want uinque rows

Comment: "5000 rows in 2 columns...2500 in each ones" contradicts itself. Perhaps you meant "5000 **values** in 2 columns...2500 in each one".

Comment: @Kerezo I accidentally came across this question but I think you can use visual basic in excel to do this.

Comment: Do you want A and B to be different ***and*** all the rows to be different? This would be like having 2500 different tickets in a lottery where two balls are chosen from a drum of 100 balls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple-minded approach using formulae. Whether it would be appropriate would depend on context.

First in the Formulas tab set calculation options to 'Manual'.

Put the following formula in a2:-

```
=RANDBETWEEN(1,100)
```

B is going to be a helper column. Put the following in B2:-

```
=RANDBETWEEN(1,99)
```

Column C is the second result that you want. Put the following in C2:-

```
=IF(B2<A2,B2,B2+1)
```

Pull the formulae down as required.

Each time you press 'Calculate Now', you will get a fresh set of random numbers.

[image]

However if you really need unique rows (every row to be different) you'd need  a different approach - could generate a set of 4-digit numbers, split them into first and last pairs of digits and filter out ones where first and second were equal.

Generate the 4-digit number in A2:-

```
=RANDBETWEEN(1,9998)
```

Take the first two-digit number plus one in B2:-

```
=INT(A2/100)+1
```

Take the second 2-digit number plus one in C2:-

```
=MOD(A2,100)+1
```

Check for invalid numbers in D2:-

```
=OR(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2,A$1:A1,0)),B2=C2)
```

Set up a running total of valid numbers in E2:-

```
=COUNTIF(D2:D$2,FALSE)
```

Here's how the second approach would look with checking for duplicate rows as well as duplicate numbers within a row. Note that you'd have to generate about 3,000 rows to get 2,500 distinct rows:-

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Excel formulas do not perform loops until a condition has been met. Any 'loop' or *array processing* must have a defined number of cycles. Further, `RAND` and `RANDBETWEEN` are volatile formulas that will recalculate anytime the workbook goes through a calculation cycle.

In VBA this would look like the following.

```
Sub Random_2500_x_2()
    Dim rw As Long
    For rw = 1 To 2500
        Cells(rw, 1) = Int((100 - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1)
        Cells(rw, 2) = Int((100 - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1)
        Do Until Cells(rw, 2).Value <> Cells(rw, 1).Value
            Cells(rw, 2) = Int((100 - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1)
        Loop
    Next rw
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

First run this tiny macro:

```
Sub dural()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    k = 1
    For i = 1 To 100
        For j = 1 To 100
            Cells(k, 1) = i
            Cells(k, 2) = j
            Cells(k, 3).Formula = "=rand()"
            k = k + 1
        Next j
    Next i
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Then sort cols **A,B,C** by column **C.**
Then pick the first 5000 rows.

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

To remove cases in which the value in column **A** is the same as the value in column **B** use this macro instead:

```
Sub dural()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    k = 1
    For i = 1 To 100
        For j = 1 To 100
            If i <> j Then
                Cells(k, 1) = i
                Cells(k, 2) = j
                Cells(k, 3).Formula = "=rand()"
                k = k + 1
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: There might still be equal rows like the third row.