# First VBA Code: Run-time Error "1004"

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

I am receiving a run-time error, but that may be the least of my problems. The logic makes sense in my head but I may not be using the correct syntax or functions. My code is below with comments and "hopes":

```
Sub Random_Points()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim Max As Integer
    Dim RandomNumber As Integer

    Max = 100 '(Max is being multiplied by the Rnd function to provide a random number between 0-100)

    For i = 2 To 100 Step 1

    RandomNumber = Int(Rnd * Max)
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("VBA").Cells(i, 2).Value = RandomNumber

    '(The for loop above with start assigned cells values starting with Cells(2,2) to Cells(100,2))
    '(I DO NOT WANT DUPLICATE VALUES...therefore after the value is assigned above I want the code to compare the newly assigned cell to all the cells above it.)

        For j = 1 To 98 Step 1

        '(...and IF the cell values are the same...)
        If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("VBA").Cells(i, 2).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("VBA").Cells(i - j, 2).Value Then

            '(...A new random number will be assigned...)
            RandomNumber = Int(Rnd * Max)
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("VBA").Cells(i, 2).Value = RandomNumber
        End If

        '(...and then re-checked vs all the others)
        Next j

        '(Next cell is assigned...loop restarts)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you debug and see the error is coming on which line?

Comment: While **unique random numbers** is an oxymoron, did you see [Generate 5000 records in 2 columns of random number that being unique](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27877861/generate-5000-records-in-2-columns-of-random-number-that-being-unique/27878188#27878188)?

Comment: Now, tell us what line you are getting the error on please.

Comment: The "IF" function is giving me the error. I'll check out the link, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is in your nested loop. As **j** increments, it approaches and finally equals **i**. Subsequently, when you use the two values in `.Cells(i - j, 2).Value`, there is no [Range.Cells property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196273.aspx) with a row number less than **1**.

The solution is to change your nested For ... Next statement so that **j** never reaches **i**.

```
'was ...
For j = 1 To 98 Step 1
'should be ...
For j = 1 To (i - 1) Step 1
```

You only need to check the values up to i in any event.

fwiw, a [WorksheetFunction object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834434.aspx)'s use of [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) and VBA's [IsError function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278547.aspx) would be faster.

```
Sub randomPoints_part_deux()
    Dim i As Long, mx As Long, randNum As Long

    mx = 100 '(mx is being multiplied by the Rnd function to provide a random number between 0-100)

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("VBA")
        'seed the column of numbers so you have something to check against
        randNum = Int(Rnd * mx)
        .Cells(2, 2) = randNum

        For i = 3 To 100 Step 1

            Do While Not IsError(Application.Match(randNum, .Range(.Cells(2, 2), .Cells(i - 1, 2)), 0))
                randNum = Int(Rnd * mx)
            Loop
            .Cells(i, 2) = randNum

        Next i
        'optional formula to count unique in C2
        .Cells(2, 3).Formula = "=SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(B2:B100, B2:B100))"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

since you don't want duplicates you can either generate random numbers and then repeatedly check if they are already used or you can generate your list first and then pull from it randomly. The second option is easier.

```
Sub Random100()

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim Max As Integer
Dim RandomNumber As Integer
Dim cNum As New Collection

Max = 100 '(Max is being multiplied by the Rnd function to provide a random number between 0-100)

For i = 0 To Max 'fill collection with 0-100 in order
    cNum.Add i
Next i

k = cNum.Count - 1
For j = 0 To k
    RandomNumber = Int(Rnd * (k - j)) + 1
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("VBA").Cells(j + 2, 2).Value = cNum(RandomNumber)
    cNum.Remove (RandomNumber)
Next j

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you explain this "RandomNumber = Int(Rnd * (k - j)) + 1" Is it constantly changing the range for the random number? Thanks.

Comment: You want to count from the larger number down when referencing your collection. so this has it pull a randome number from 0 to however many are left in the collection (K -J). Without that it will break everytime you get halfway through the collection and it has removed 50 and then tries to reference spot 51.

Answer (score 0):

If your purpose is to get a range of unique values, then a better approach would be to shuffle a serie:

```
Const MIN = 1
Const MAX = 98

Dim values(MIN To MAX, 0 To 0) As Double, i&, irand&

' generate all the values
For i = MIN To MAX
  values(i, 0) = i
Next

' shuffle the values
For i = MIN To MAX
  irand = MIN + Math.Round(Rnd * (MAX - MIN))
  value = values(i, 0)
  values(i, 0) = values(irand, 0)
  values(irand, 0) = value
Next

' copy the values to the sheet
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("VBA").Range("A2").Resize(MAX - MIN + 1, 1) = values
```